# Assigning value into unordered_map pointer after creating a instance of it

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, c++-cli

I'm using a unordered map pointer because of C++/Cli on Visual Studio 2008 (Using Windows Forms Application), but I can't assign a value to it, it throws an error, as my code example is showing

```
 //...
    public ref class Login: public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:

    unordered_map< std::string, std::string >* Accounts;

    Test(void)
    {
        this->Accounts = new unordered_map<std::string, std::string>();
        this->Accounts["hello"] = "test"; // The Error is in this line, this is the line 37
        cout << this->Accounts["hello"];
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //


    }
    //...
```

Error given:

> Error 4 error C2107: illegal index, indirection not allowed
>   C:\Projects\Test\Login.h 37

I hope my code was clear enough so you can visualize it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really need `Accounts` to be a pointer?

Comment: I do because in C++/CLI they don't allow you to set it without being by pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Accounts` is a pointer, you need to dereference it:

```
(*this->Accounts)["hello"] = "test";
cout << (*this->Accounts)["hello"];
```

Comment: it threw an error "error C2059: syntax error : '('" in the same line   , maybe the error is on my instance as its shown in my question, do you think thats it ?

Comment: I tested your new answer and I got another error: "error C2107: illegal index, indirection not allowed"

Comment: haha finally you got it right, just kidding, thanks for the answer and the effort. :)